# Sharepoint Online Search Rest API User Profile Properties Custom Fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API Search Service we need to get Custom Properties  in SharePoint Online.

I used the following query get all user's user profiles properties

```
https://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&selectproperties='FirstName,LastName,OHPosition'
```

Result:

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>OHPosition</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

From the above result I got value type is `null`, but this is `String`. Any one can you suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sharepoint 2013, when the creation of custom column, you must report that it should be searchable, so in their requests the values it appeared normal.

In this post has a more detailed about this.

http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2013/01/retrieving-values-of-managed-properties-in-sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api/